# Is "$\forall X\in\Gamma\forall Y\in \Sigma\exists x(x\in X\wedge x\in Y)$" a well-formed second-order logic formula?

Tags: first-order-logic, second-order-logic

I am trying to characterize some properties of argumentation framework of P.M.Dung with second-order logic formula. Such a framework is  $AF=\langle Arg, R\rangle$, where $Arg$ is a finite set of arguments and  $R$ is a binary relation on $Arg$. We use lowercase letters (i.e. $x,\ y,\ z,\ \cdots$) to denote elements of $Arg$, and uppercase letters (i.e., $X,\ Y,\ Z,\ \cdots$) to denote subsets of $Arg$. $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ are fixed subsets of $2^{Arg}$, i.e. $\Gamma\subseteq 2^{Arg}$ and $\Sigma\subseteq 2^{Arg}$. Those are the backgrounds. Here are my qustions:

1. Is "$\forall X\in\Gamma\forall Y\in \Sigma\exists x(x\in X\wedge
       x\in Y)$" a well-formed second-order logic formula? Note that "$\forall X\in\Gamma\varphi(X)$'' is short for ''$\forall X((X\in\Gamma)\wedge\varphi(X))$''
2. Can I describe a set $\Delta$ of arguments as follows: $\Delta=\{x\in
       Arg\mid \forall X\in\Gamma\forall Y\in \Sigma(x\in X\wedge x\in Y)
       \}$

Comment: Usually, predicate logic has not variables for sets, but for predicates.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But it is clear that second-order logic allows predicates to be variables.

Comment: But you have $x \in X \in \Gamma$. $x$ is an individual variable, i.e. it stands for an object (a formula ?). If so, $X$ is a set of formulas (in SOL we have $X(x)$) and $\Gamma$ is what ?

Comment: When you write $\varphi(X)$ what is it ? In SOL it is a formula with a free predicate variable.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA If $X$ is fixed, $\forall x\in X\varphi(x)$ is a first-order formula. Similarly, if $\Gamma$ is fixed,  is $\forall X\in\Gamma\varphi(X)$ a second-order formula?

Comment: On the face of it, the answer to 1 is "no"; you've written a third order formula.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Then $\forall x\in X\varphi(x)$ is a first-order formula ?

Comment: No, that would be a second order formula.

Comment: If $Arg$ is the set of your individuals, and $R$ a relation on those individuals, the only first order formulas are those that use $R$ and $=$ as the only basic predicates; no $\in$.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Can I describe a set $\Delta$ of arguments as follows: $\Delta=\{x\in
    Arg\mid \forall X\in\Gamma\forall Y\in \Sigma(x\in X\wedge x\in Y)
    \}$

Answer (score 1):

What you have written for (1) is not a second order formula, but a *third order* formula. A first order formula has variables that range over individuals (i.e. elements of $Arg$), and no other kind of variable; a second order formula has variables that range over individuals, and variables that range over sets of individuals (i.e. over elements of $2^{Arg}$). The formula written here also has $\Gamma,\Sigma$ ranging over elements of $2^{2^{Arg}}$, which is what makes it third order.

What you have down for (2) is a perfectly sensible notation, if still involving a third order formula. But without knowing anything about the logical setup in the source you're working from, there's no telling if it actually exists. Presumably, if you're caring about second-order or third-order formulas, and are not just working set-theoretically, you should be working in some particular second order theory, and that theory will provide you with some comprehension axioms that tell you what formulas determine sets. Without knowing the comprehension axioms available to you, all that can be said is that it's not syntactically malformed.

Comment: $\Gamma$ and $\Sigma$ are not quantified in the formula. If they were, then certainly they should be parsed as variables of the object language. But as explained in the text, $\Gamma$ and $\Sigma$ are names (meta-variables) for some fixed sets.

Comment: @frabala - They don't need to be quantified to make it third order; if the poster is using $\in\Gamma$ and asking whether it's good second order syntax, I'm going to take the $\in$ seriously. But it is the case that the higher order variables could be omitted in this case in favor or a pair of new predicate symbols on sets.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine But do you agree that  "$\forall X\in\Gamma\forall Y\in \Sigma\exists x(x\in X\wedge
    x\in Y)$" is a  first-order formula in set theory? And why?

Comment: @Marvin - If it's a formula of set theory, then it's first order because that's what kind of theory set theory is. The variables $x,X$ and $\Gamma$, for instance, would just be different styles of writing variables that refer to individuals (which in set theory, are sets). One wouldn't, then, construe them as belonging to different sorts built into the logic.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Thanks a lot. So, the binary relation $R$ on$Arg$ in the framework $AF$ can be understood as the binary relation $\in$ in set theory, right? Merely, individuals are arguments in $AF$,  while sets in set theory.